# `titlesec` package - uneven marginal section numbers

Tags: titlesec

I am using `book` class and have made the section numbers appear in the right margin with the `titlesec` package. Whenever there's a `\noindent` command, the marginal section number seems to shift to the left. This causes the section numbers look uneven. The `MWE` is as follows:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[rightmargin] 
{} 
{\it\thesection}
{0em}
{}

\titlespacing{\section}
{1em}{1em}{0em}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter-name}

\section{}
\lipsum[1][1]\par
\section{}
\noindent\lipsum[1][2]\par
\section{}
\lipsum[1][3]\par
\section{}
\lipsum[1][4-6]\par
\section{}
\lipsum[2-4][12-18]

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is as follows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPL3X.png]

Note that the 5th section number overlaps with the section content.

How can I make the section numbers appear in a uniform way in the right margin irrespective of the text contained in the respective section?

Regards.

Comment: It's unclear why you'd want `\noindent`.

Comment: @egreg : My use case is such that I am using \section just to use it as a counter. And the text that is contained in each section shouldn't be indented.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong tool. However, I'm still asking why some paragraph should be indented and some not.

Comment: Actually the use case is that I am formatting Sanskrit verses and their Roman transliteration. So all the lines should be aligned properly. 1. The `verse` package by default doesn't satisfy my requirements. 2. And yes, I maybe misusing the `\section` command, but right now I have to get the work done and cannot spare time to explore other ways, such as using a new `counter` OR tinkering with `verse` package etc.. 3. But I want to learn LaTeX in depth in the near future. You are most welcome to share your thoughts/suggestions w.r.t the three points.

Comment: Instead of \noindent you could use `\hspace*{-\parindent}\lipsum[1][3]`. This will nullify the indent too but not move the number.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: that's really smart! Wow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With indent at each new paragraph, new code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[rightmargin] 
{} 
{\it\thesection}
{0em}
{}

\titlespacing{\section}
{1em}{1em}{1em} % <--- changed
\begin{document}
    \chapter{chapter-name}
    % indent for each new paragrapf/section
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1][1]\par
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1][2]\par
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1][3]\par
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1][4-6]\par
    \section{}
    \lipsum[2-4][12-18]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT: If you dont want indent for all new paragraph, write this line in the preamble:

```
\parindent=0mm
```

The new output in this case is:

[image]

Comment: `\parindent=0pt` affects the whole document. Is there any way to apply it locally only to the particular section? I tried the followings: `\noindent` in `\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{}{\noindent\itshape\thesection}{0pt}{}[\noindent]` or in `\titlespacing{\section}{2em}{1em}{0em}[\noindent]` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: _apply it locally only to the particular section_ sorry the wording is not clear here. I meant locally in the section definition, so it would be applied in every `\section{}`

Answer (score 0):

With indent at each new paragraph, new code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[rightmargin] 
{} 
{\it\thesection}
{0em}
{}

\titlespacing{\section}
{1em}{1em}{1em} % <--- changed
\begin{document}
    \chapter{chapter-name}
    % indent for each new paragrapf/section
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1][1]\par
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1][2]\par
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1][3]\par
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1][4-6]\par
    \section{}
    \lipsum[2-4][12-18]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: If you dont want paragraph indent everywhere, add in your preamble the line \parindent=0mm. In this case the output is:

[image]

Comment: I think you have answered this question twice.